# Using Big Query API to ingest data into table partitioned by time but getting SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a CSV file into a Bigquery table, partitioned by month.

The code is returning the following error:

`google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Syntax error: Expected end of input but got ":" at [17:24]`

The syntax error seems to be referring to a colon that is part of a URL string I am trying to insert into the table:
https**:**//www.example.com

Seems odd that this would prompt an error given that it is just part of a string.

Do I need to escape the colon in some way? If so, how?

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_gbq
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
from datetime import datetime

query =
    '''
INSERT INTO
<<project id>>.<<Dataset>>.<<table>>(_PARTITIONTIME,
url,
title,
h1
)
SELECT {},{},{},{}
'''
now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


def run():

    client = \
        storage.Client.from_service_account_json('<<path to file>>'
            )
    bq_client = \
        bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('<<path to file>>'
            )
    bucket = client.bucket('<<bucket name>>')
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs()
    list_temp_raw = []
    for file in blobs:
        filename = file.name
        temp = pd.read_csv('gs://<<bucket name>>/' + filename)
        list_temp_raw.append(temp)
    df = pd.concat(list_temp_raw)
    df = df[cols]
    for i in range(len(df.head())):
        **load_query = query.format(
            now,
            df.loc[i, 'url'],
            df.iloc[i, 'title'],
            df.loc[i, 'h1']
            )
        query_job = bq_client.query(load_query)**
        query_job.result()
run()
```

Comment: Try adding parentheses like `SELECT {},{},{},"{}"`.

P.S. It is better to ask a new question, because old answer is not relevant now. This is confusing for others.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure... but maybe adding TIMESTAMP to the query or waiting for the job to complete may help:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_gbq
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
from datetime import datetime

query =
    '''
INSERT INTO
<<project id>>.<<Dataset>>.<<table>>(_PARTITIONTIME,
a,
b,
c,
d,
)
SELECT TIMESTAMP("{}"),{},{},{},{}
'''
now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


def run():

    client = \
        storage.Client.from_service_account_json('<<path to file>>'
            )
    bq_client = \
        bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('<<path to file>>'
            )
    bucket = client.bucket('<<bucket name>>')
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs()
    list_temp_raw = []
    for file in blobs:
        filename = file.name
        temp = pd.read_csv('gs://<<bucket name>>/' + filename)
        list_temp_raw.append(temp)
    df = pd.concat(list_temp_raw)
    df = df[cols]
    for i in range(len(df.head())):
        load_query = query.format(
            now,
            df.loc[i, 'a'],
            df.iloc[i, 'b'],
            df.loc[i, 'c'],
            df.loc[i, 'd']
            )
        query_job = bq_client.query(load_query)
        query_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
run()
```